# Power Bi Embedding Paginated Reports

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am having difficulties setting my python application up to embed a paginated power BI report. I can get it working fine on a normal report/visual but I can not on a paginated report.

Does anyone have an example of python code they use to render the paginated report inside their application?

I have been trolling the web and documentation and I just must be missing some simple config.

```
def get_embed_params_for_multiple_reports(self, workspace_id, report_ids, additional_dataset_ids=None):
        '''Get embed params for multiple reports for a single workspace
    Args:
        workspace_id (str): Workspace Id
        report_ids (list): Report Ids
        additional_dataset_ids (list, optional): Dataset Ids which are different than the ones bound to the reports. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
        EmbedConfig: Embed token and Embed URLs
    '''

    # Note: This method is an example and is not consumed in this sample app

    dataset_ids = []

    # To store multiple report info
    reports = []

    for report_id in report_ids:
        report_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/reports/{report_id}'
        api_response = requests.get(report_url, headers=self.get_request_header())

        if api_response.status_code != 200:
            abort(api_response.status_code, description=f'Error while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')

        api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
        report_config = ReportConfig(api_response['id'], api_response['name'], api_response['embedUrl'])
        reports.append(report_config.__dict__)
        dataset_ids.append(api_response['datasetId'])

    # Append additional dataset to the list to achieve dynamic binding later
    if additional_dataset_ids is not None:
        dataset_ids.extend(additional_dataset_ids)

    embed_token = self.get_embed_token_for_multiple_reports_single_workspace(report_ids, dataset_ids, workspace_id)
    embed_config = EmbedConfig(embed_token.tokenId, embed_token.token, embed_token.tokenExpiry, reports)
    return json.dumps(embed_config.__dict__)



def get_embed_token_for_multiple_reports_multiple_workspaces(self, report_ids, dataset_ids, target_workspace_ids=None):
        '''Get Embed token for multiple reports, multiple datasets, and optional target workspaces

    Args:
        report_ids (list): Report Ids
        dataset_ids (list): Dataset Ids
        target_workspace_ids (list, optional): Workspace Ids. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
        EmbedToken: Embed token
    '''

    # Note: This method is an example and is not consumed in this sample app

    request_body = EmbedTokenRequestBody()

    for dataset_id in dataset_ids:
        request_body.datasets.append({'id': dataset_id})

    for report_id in report_ids:
        request_body.reports.append({'id': report_id})

    if target_workspace_ids is not None:
        for target_workspace_id in target_workspace_ids:
            request_body.targetWorkspaces.append({'id': target_workspace_id})

    # Generate Embed token for multiple workspaces, datasets, and reports. Refer https://aka.ms/MultiResourceEmbedToken
    embed_token_api = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken'
    api_response = requests.post(embed_token_api, data=json.dumps(request_body.__dict__), headers=self.get_request_header())

    if api_response.status_code != 200:
        abort(api_response.status_code, description=f'Error while retrieving Embed token\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')

    api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
    embed_token = EmbedToken(api_response['tokenId'], api_response['token'], api_response['expiration'])
    return embed_token
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that the normal report and visuals are getting embedded, we can assume that the access part with embed URLs and the embed tokens is working as intended.

For Paginated reports, since you have not mentioned what configuration you have used for paginated reports, make sure that the embed config contains the `IPaginatedReportSettings`:

```
export interface IEmbedConfigurationBase {
    ...
    settings?: IPaginatedReportSettings;
}
```

For embedding **Paginated Reports**, we need to enable the paginated report workload on your capacity and then assign the workspace containing the paginated report to it.

**Note:** This is only necessary for Embedded Gen1.

To enable the paginated report, Sign into Power BI > Admin portal > Capacity settings.

References:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports?tabs=customers#step-4---enable-paginated-reports-workload
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-models/ipaginatedreportsettings